# String interpolation not working Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a dynamic property in my card value as below -

```
<div class="card-block pt-2 pb-0">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body white text-left">
            <h3 class="font-large-1 mb-0">{{totalprofiles}}</h3>
                <span>Total Cost</span>
        </div>
        <div class="media-right white text-right">
            <i class="icon-bulb font-large-1"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The property `totalprofiles` is a simple number field in my component, however it doesn't get interpolated in the card or any where in the html template. Below is the code from component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard2',
    templateUrl: './dashboard2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard2.component.scss']
})

export class Dashboard2Component {
    totalprofiles = 100;
}
```

I am trying to figure out why. I am using Angular CLI version (7.0.2).

Update --

After doing multiple tries I can confirm that nothing seems wrong with the `html` template. I replaced the html template with the below code -

```
<div>
    <h3>{{totalprofiles}}</h3>
</div>
```

Even this doesn't seem to be working, so I guess it is something with the component. Still trying to figure out and I will update after some more research.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in the html.. any error in the console?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** by including a [mcve]. See also [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). I recommend you include a https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @PankajParkar , that is the problem nothing seems wrong with the html and component as well, I don't see any error on console too. :(

Comment: I have replicated the same code which you given in your question in the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8bkyq and its working fine.. Only difference you can see in this link is component name as ```app``` instead of ```dashboard2```..

Comment: I also tried same in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvk21p and it works fine there. Now the question is what might be wrong ?

Comment: @Jeet, This is the code that you have given and everything is working fine even for you also.. Unless you provide some working example with the error you facing, it would be difficult to address the answer.. Hope you already know everything about the stackoverflow community for right solution..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur I totally agree with you, I respect the community and honor its code, however I am clueless right now about approaching to solution for this problem and don't know where to look for it. This seems very strange to me as well, Is it any configuration in Angular or is it the way the variable gets loaded into DOM or what ? Need to get some pointer where should I start looking at.

Comment: Two things you can try: (1) Replace `{{totalprofiles}}` with some simple text (e.g. `Hello world`) to see if that works, (2) Retype the interpolation markup and the declaration of `totalprofiles` in code, in case some hidden character would have been inserted by mistake.

Comment: I did that, it doesn't even work for simple text. tried multiple time with different variable name as well. Nothing seems working.

Comment: @Jeet we can't guess the error, if you have reproducible problem in plunker/stackblitz then we can help you to fix the same :)

Comment: I totally understand, I wish I could reproduce it. I am going to delete the questions after sometime, since it doesn't seems working the larger community either. Will wait for some time and will delete it after some more try.

Comment: I can understand what @Jeet is filling as i also have component and a normal variable `starrating:string ='4'` on the `TS` file is not getting interpreted in {{}} on my DOM in `<h1>` tag, no idea what is wrong,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was difficult to figure out and I couldn't find any answer, however I was able to solve the problem by creating another component and copying the template and component code from old components. Though this was more of a work-around but it did solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i fixed it declaring the type of the variable declared to any.

```
export class Dashboard2Component {
    totalprofiles:any = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be the issue with your editor while using live server ,angular runs in port number  http://localhost:4200/ your ide live server might run on different port .

1. first solution ,directly run your project with this  http://localhost:4200/
2. second solution , make  use of ,
   ng serve --port5500 if its a live server in vscode editor,
   or use the port number that your favorite Ide uses by default as mentioned above.

ng serve --port;

this will resolve your issue.